# problem showing image after switching activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity

i'm having the above problem when switching my activity. In the first activity i have a GalleryView showing all my images and an ImageView show the selected image from the gallery. Now i want to switch to the next activity and keep the same image from the ImageView on screen in the second activity. Here is how i show my images:

```
Integer[] imageIDs = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));        
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {                
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);                
                imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            }
        });
```

Is there like an id or something saying what's on screen at the moment of the switch? How can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Do you want to save the State of the Activity with the Gallery (that should Android do automatically, i think) or do you want to show the selected Image from the ImageView in a second activity? If it's the latter you want to do, just put the imageID (ResourceId, or array position) as Extra Data into the Intent you're using to call your second Activity.

Hope i'm not totally missing your point.

Comment: I wanted to do the second option, to show the selected Image from the ImageView in a second activity, i did what you said with the putExtra, and it worked beautifly. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Nice to hear. Could you accept one of the answers though? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is storing the 'selected image' either in the form of a Resource ID or a URI or even just keeping the imageView object if you really want to, in your [Application Instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) -- this is maintained between activities.

Just create a class that extends the Application class, and make it a static object, so that you can always call getInstance()

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
        private static MyApplication singleton;
        private Uri selectedImage;

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
            return singleton;
    }

    public void setSelectedImage(Uri uri) { selectedImage = uri; }
    public Uri getSelectedImage() { return selectedImage; }
}
```

This will work across your activities.  But as wonne said putting the information as an EXTRA in the intent will work as well.

Comment: Using statics is not a good practice for android. To implement a singleton or something to share data between activities it's better to create a Service. Or you could use system services e.g. ContentProvider.

Comment: I will try this method too because i'm interested in sigletons in Android. Thanks for the advices :p